# Need to change the c++ console text size

Tags: c++, text, console, size

I need to change the **text size on console** using *c++* . For example i am writing the software name that needs to be of greater size rather than small/default size.

Comment: This is platform-dependent. Consult the docs of your windowing system (WinAPI, X11 etc.) or the toolkit you're using on top of it (Qt, WxWidgets etc.).

Comment: With most consoles you can't change the font in just a small part. You can use ASCII art, or  s p a c e d  text, or bold/color for emphasis. Look up the NCurses library for some fairly platform independent console handling.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx) to do so. Pass an appropriate `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` structure, valid combinations for `dwFontSize` are those which you can find when you try to change the font size manually via the UI.